# Do we have to check if file exist for each when delete multiple files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

In the code below, I check if file uploaded by only checking on single folder but I noticed that the code stops if the file /new/name.ext is not exist.

Do we have to check for each to continue with code? **Is there a way to continue with code without having to check if file exist for every file - or even easier way?**

```
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/thumb/" + strGuid  + strExt))) {
       System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/icons/" + strGuid  + strExt));
       System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/thumb/" + strGuid  + strExt));
       System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/new/" + strGuid + strExt));
       System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/large/" + strGuid  + strExt));
       System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/full/" + strGuid + strExt));
   }
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If the file does not exist the Delete method will throw an exception

Comment: well... if nothing else you could create a function that checks that it exists prior to attempting to delete it :/

Comment: No, you can not proceeds as that will throw you exception file not found. Instead you can collect all the available file list in a collection and with the help of loop do your IF {} part.

Comment: You can create your own "SafeDelete" function...that takes the filename..checks for existence...and if it exists...deletes it.

Comment: [This is an example of a SafeDelete function](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths/blob/master/Source/Runtime/ZlpSafeFileOperations.cs#L30) in one of my class libraries.

Comment: Am I looking at a different version of [`Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) to everyone else? "If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown."

Comment: File.Delete doesn't throw an exception for a missing file, as Damien already pointed out. But it will throw DirectoryNotFoundException if the *directory* doesn't exist. So then the question becomes, why are you trying to delete a file from a nonexistent directory?

Comment: Thanks for all of you. The above code is already inside try/catch . thought that will help not to throw an exception. some of my pages contains all mentioned folders and other have less, If anyone can help with a "short" delete loop that I can apply on all will be thankful.

Comment: Good question @Joe White , so the problem is the directory not the file exist or not. I think I can fix that.

Comment: [Don't use `if (File.Exists(file)) { File.Delete(file); }`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951247/should-my-method-throw-its-own-exception-or-let-net-throw-if-a-file-doesnt-ex/32951293). Just attempt to delete the file.

Comment: Thanks @UweKeim for tat library. If you kindly aware with a more simple SafeDelete code I will be thankful .... beginners :)

Answer (score 1):

Although I normally wouldn't recommend "eating" exceptions, this might be an exception to that exception rule.

I'd write a single method:

```
void DeleteFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
         if(File.Exists(filePath)
         {
             File.Delete(filePath);
         }
    }
    catch(DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
         // depending on your environment you might
         // be prompted for some comment to indicate
         // that you meant to do this because
         // it's usually bad.
    }        
}
```

Only catch `DirectoryNotFoundException`. If the directory doesn't exist then the file doesn't exist.

The reason for placing this in a separate method is because if you're concerned about this scenario, then you don't want one `Delete` to throw an exception that keeps the subsequent deletes from executing.

It doesn't entirely sit well with me to use exception handling for something when there's another way to check. It's better to verify that the file exists. This is only for extreme paranoia.

Here's a question - how likely are these files and directories to get deleted *before* you delete them? And if one file throws an exception that prevents the others from getting deleted, how serious are the consequences? It might be better to just allow the delete to fail then to get extra paranoid and overdo the checking an exception handling. But it's a short method so if you're worried about it it can't hurt. But this sort of thing can become habit-forming.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. This worked for me and "safely" deleted targeted files even if one of the directories is missing. I will also have a look on the SafeDelete function that Uwe Keim mentioned above but wished if there is something shorter.

Comment: thank you .. +1 .. I added an answer but will not mark hoping someone do better

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just iterate through all the files in folder ..cats/ and its sub folders with right attributes(name / extension)? Then you could just use System.IO.File.Exists().

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path/to/file.ext)){
    System.IO.File.Delete(Path/to/file.ext);
}
```

The iteration could be done finding all files with

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*ProfileHandler.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

and then just doing something like:

```
foreach(file in files){
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path/to/file.ext)){
        System.IO.File.Delete(Path/to/file.ext);
    }

}
```

E: Sorry for not being able to give you the exact syntax, currently using a computer without a proper IDE to write and test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [UweKeim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim) advice and the source of the [ZetaLongPaths
 library](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths/blob/master/Source/Runtime/ZlpSafeFileOperations.cs#L30) he mentioned in his comment (Thankful for you) and since I don't need all the Long File Name/Path issue so I have picked few pieces to handle my little application. I didn't fully tested it but it works fine for the code in my question. Hope someone can check and provide better tested code.

```
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;


  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // ZetaLongPaths/Source/Runtime/ZlpSafeFileOperations.cs 
  // https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths/blob/master/Source/Runtime/ZlpSafeFileOperations.cs#L30
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  namespace MyNameSpace {

      public class FileHandling {


          //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          ///<summary>
          /// Simple File Operations Handling 
          ///</summary>
          ///<remarks>
          /// 
          ///</remarks>
          //------------------------------------------------------------------------------


          public static bool SafeFileExists(FileInfo filePath) {
              return filePath != null && SafeFileExists(filePath.FullName);
          }

          public static bool SafeFileExists(string filePath) {
              return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) && System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);
          }
          public static void SafeMoveFile(FileInfo sourcePath, FileInfo dstFilePath) {
              SafeMoveFile(
                  sourcePath?.FullName.ToString(),
                  dstFilePath?.FullName);
          }
          public static void SafeDeleteFile(FileInfo filePath) {
              if (filePath != null) {
                  SafeDeleteFile(filePath.FullName);
              }
          }

          public static void SafeDeleteFile(
              string filePath) {
              Trace.TraceInformation(@"About to safe-delete file '{0}'.", filePath);

              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) && SafeFileExists(filePath)) {
                  try {
                      var attributes = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath);

                      // Remove read-only attributes.
                      if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) != 0) {
                          System.IO.File.SetAttributes(
                              filePath,
                              attributes & (~(FileAttributes.ReadOnly)));
                      }

                      System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                  } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException x) {
                      var newFilePath =
                          $@"{filePath}.{Guid.NewGuid():N}.deleted";

                      Trace.TraceWarning(@"Caught UnauthorizedAccessException while deleting file '{0}'. " +
                                         @"Renaming now to '{1}'. {2}", filePath, newFilePath, x.Message);

                      try {
                          System.IO.File.Move(
                              filePath,
                              newFilePath);
                      } catch (Win32Exception x2) {
                          Trace.TraceWarning(@"Caught IOException while renaming upon failed deleting file '{0}'. " +
                                             @"Renaming now to '{1}'. {2}", filePath, newFilePath, x2.Message);
                      }
                  } catch (Win32Exception x) {
                      var newFilePath =
                          $@"{filePath}.{Guid.NewGuid():N}.deleted";

                      Trace.TraceWarning(@"Caught IOException while deleting file '{0}'. " +
                                         @"Renaming now to '{1}'. {2}", filePath, newFilePath, x.Message);

                      try {
                          System.IO.File.Move(
                              filePath,
                              newFilePath);
                      } catch (Win32Exception x2) {
                          Trace.TraceWarning(@"Caught IOException while renaming upon failed deleting file '{0}'. " +
                                             @"Renaming now to '{1}'. {2}", filePath, newFilePath, x2.Message);
                      }
                  }
              } else {
                  Trace.TraceInformation(@"Not safe-deleting file '{0}', " +
                                         @"because the file does not exist.", filePath);
              }
          }
          public static void SafeMoveFile(string sourcePath, string dstFilePath) {
              Trace.TraceInformation(@"About to safe-move file from '{0}' to '{1}'.", sourcePath, dstFilePath);

              if (sourcePath == null || dstFilePath == null) {
                  Trace.TraceInformation(
                      string.Format(
                          @"Source file path or destination file path does not exist. " +
                          @"Not moving."
                          ));
              } else {
                  if (SafeFileExists(sourcePath)) {
                      SafeDeleteFile(dstFilePath);

                      var d = Path.GetDirectoryName(dstFilePath);

                      if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(d)) {
                          Trace.TraceInformation(@"Creating non-existing folder '{0}'.", d);
                          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(d);
                      }

                      System.IO.File.Move(sourcePath, dstFilePath);
                  } else {
                      Trace.TraceInformation(@"Source file path to move does not exist: '{0}'.", sourcePath);
                  }
              }
          }

      }
  }
```

## Then tested with

```
   if (MyNameSpace.FileHandling.SafeFileExists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/thumb/" + strGuid  + strExt))) {

      MyNameSpace.FileHandling.SafeDeleteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/icons/" + strGuid  + strExt).ToString());
      MyNameSpace.FileHandling.SafeDeleteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/thumb/" + strGuid  + strExt).ToString());
      MyNameSpace.FileHandling.SafeDeleteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/new/" + strGuid + strExt).ToString());
      MyNameSpace.FileHandling.SafeDeleteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/large/" + strGuid  + strExt).ToString());
      MyNameSpace.FileHandling.SafeDeleteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/products/cats/full/" + strGuid + strExt).ToString());

   }
```