# FileInfo returned from DirectoryInfo.GetFiles doesn't point to file?

Tags: c#, .net, file

This method I call from a backgroundworker dowork event

```
void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    try
    {
        files = root.GetFiles("*.cs");
        int Vara = File.ReadAllText(files[0].Name).Contains("namespace") ? 1 : 0;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }    
}
```

The problem is that i'm getting exception on the line:

```
int Vara = File.ReadAllText(files[0].Name).Contains("namespace") ? 1 : 0;
```

> Could not find file 'D:\C-Sharp\Search_Text_In_Files\Search_Text_In_Files\Search_Text_In_Files\bin\Debug\Logger.cs'

Comment: Is the file there or has it been deleted or is it open in another application? To check if the file is there you could use the File.Exists before the ReadAllText.

Comment: @PaulF if `File.ReadAllText(path)` is complaining that `path` doesn't exist, what is `File.Exists(path)` going to add?

Comment: @CodeCaster - the OP said _Could not find file_ not that the path does not exist.

Comment: @PaulF semantics. I meant the same ("no file exists at path" if you want).

Comment: @CodeCaster - the benefit that will be achieved will be avoiding the exception - with the above code, even modified with your solution, there may be an issue with getting the list of files & then processing them if the file is deleted prior to being processed.

Comment: @PaulF avoiding the exception is simply hiding the error. No file will ever be found using this code, so it is not a good suggestion to add `File.Exists()`. Also, [the file disappearing can also happen between the calls to `File.Exists()` and `File.ReadAllText()`, so you shouldn't use that pattern at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951247/should-my-method-throw-its-own-exception-or-let-net-throw-if-a-file-doesnt-ex/32951293#32951293).

Comment: It all depends on point of view - if I am looking for files that contain a particular string & the file no longer exists then why report it as an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FileInfo.Name` you're only getting the filename, not the full path.

Hence you're trying to read the file relative to the current directory, where it doesn't exist.

Obtain the full path instead, i.e. `FileInfo.FullName` instead of `FileInfo.Name`.

If you want to read all files, you should loop over the files instead of only reading the first (`files[0]`), the latter of which is dangerous anyway, because that will throw if there are no files found.

```
foreach (var fileInfo in files)
{
    int Vara = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName).Contains("namespace") ? 1 : 0;

}
```

Comment: Exactly. He could have found this out himself by comparing this `rootpath` with the path shown in the exception. Clear case of not reading the exception itself properly.

Comment: Right FullName does the job. The question is if doing files[0] will search all the files in files var each iteration ? Or i need to make something like other thread and loop there on files and make the search there in the other thread ? files[0] is only the first file in files. But the method is recursive so each time files contain another number of files.

Comment: You mean the other answer? Yes, you need to loop over all files, `files[0]` will only search the first file.

Comment: Then how should i check or handle a file not found exception ? I saw your discussion with PaulF above.

Comment: @מנימנחם just catch that exception and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `Name` to `FullName` of `FileInfo` object:

```
void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo[] files = root.GetFiles("*.cs");

        foreach(FileInfo fileInfo in files) 
        {
            int Vara = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName).Contains("namespace") ? 1 : 0;

            // do something with Vara
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }    
}
```

Reference [FileInfo.FullName Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ["Try this" is not an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain). Please explain what problem the OP's code had, and how your suggestion fixes that.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Corrected